# Column aliasing in SELECT statements doesn't work with SQuirrel SQL + Firebird

Tags: sql, jdbc, firebird, squirrel-sql, jaybird

I tried add an column alias in SELECT statement using SQuirrel SQL 3.4 + Firebird 1.5 + Driver JDBC Jaybird 2.2.[0|1] (JVM 1.7.0_03), but doesn't work. The column aliased appears with the original name of column. In another tool (DBExpert) the same statement works fine.

**Statement**: `SELECT column1 AS alias1, column2 FROM table;`
**Resultant columns name in SquirrelSQL**: `column1 - column2`
**Resultant columns name in DBExpert**: `alias1 - column2`

Tried add ' and " around alias name, but also not work.

Someone have an idea?

Edit: I updated the JDBC Jaybird driver to 2.2.1 version (released Sept/30) and the problem remains.

**Edit 2: Problem fixed!**

The problenm is caused by default preferences of Squirrel SQL.

To fix it, go to "File" -> "Global Preferences", in tab "Data Type Controls" find "General (applies to all types)" and mark the combo-box "Use column labels instead of column names in result headers".

See the screenshot: http://i1-win.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/SQuirrel-SQL-Client_4.png?1345342622

Enjoy.

Comment: Problem fixed. See the question "edit 2".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is due to confusion in the JDBC specs (at least historically) and a change in Jaybird with regard to what it reports as columnNames and columnLabels in the resultset metadata. As far as I am aware in JDBC 2.0 and earlier, the distinction between columnName and columnLabel was not well defined, so in almost all cases `getColumnName()` returned the same value as `getColumnLabel()` (ie the AS alias if specified).

With JDBC 3.0 a sharper distinction was made: the `columnName` was to be the name of the underlying column in a table (if any), the `columnLabel` is the AS-alias if specified and otherwise the `columnName`. Jaybird 2.1.6 and earlier used to return the same value for `getColumnLabel()` and `getColumnName()` (ie the `columnLabel`), this was changed in Jaybird 2.2.

Apparently Squirrel defaults to the non-JDBC compliant option of `columnName`, instead of `columnLabel`. As you already found out: there is an option to get it to use the `columnLabel` instead. The other option you have is to use Jaybird 2.2.1 or higher and add the connection property `columnLabelForName=true`.

Comment: Your explanation was very enlightening. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

In Squirrel this needs to be set up on:

> File > Global Preferences > Data Type Controls > Check: **Use column labels
>   instead of column names in result headers**