# Why column alias is not set with the keyword "AS"?

Tags: jdbc, db2, db2-luw

As mentioned in the title, I am unable to perform some simple query using the `AS` keyword. For example

```
SELECT COLUMN1 AS TESTING FROM TESTINGTABLE;
```

I get the following result.

```
COLUMN1
-------------
VALUE1
```

instead of

```
TESTING
--------------
VALUE1
```

However for

```
select 'abcd' as TESTING from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

I can get the following result

```
TESTING
--------------
abcd
```

Please help to give some direction... my db2 version is DB2 v11.1.0.1527

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column aliasing in SELECT statements doesn't work with SQuirrel SQL + Firebird](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709814/column-aliasing-in-select-statements-doesnt-work-with-squirrel-sql-firebird)

Comment: See this [page in the manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_c0052593.html) and try setting the JDBC connection property `useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics`

Comment: You might need to provide some more context: **where are you having this problem**?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i encounter this issues in sql developer, i connect to my db2 database after imported db2jcc4.jar

Comment: @mustaccio i using sql developer to check the result....

Answer (score 0):

strange, try this formats:

```
SELECT COLUMN1 TESTING FROM TESTINGTABLE;
```

or this :

```
SELECT COLUMN1 AS "TESTING" FROM TESTINGTABLE;
```

Comment: on other table same problem?

Comment: are you on squirrel?

Comment: i using sql developer, to connect db2, imported db2jcc4.jar as third party jdbc drivers....

Comment: i believe not only in software hitting the issues, coz in my server i also hit null pointer error, i check back my query it did return result... just that the column name did not change to the expected alias name....

Comment: rerad this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709814/column-aliasing-in-select-statements-doesnt-work-with-squirrel-sql-firebird

Comment: i thing its a parameter of your jdbc